# Retrieving search data from database using jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin for better data input in my ASP.NET web application.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

However, I think I have somehow lost in this plugin.
I would like to ask what I should do in order to use this autocomplete function with the data retrieve from database?

I expect Ajax should be used for the real-time search,
but I have no idea how it can be done after looking at the demo in the website above.

Thanks so much.

**Update:**

Here is the code I have tried, doesn't work, but no error in firebug too.

```
                $('#FirstName').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Contact/FirstNameLookup?firstName=",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                "firstName": $('#FirstName').val() 
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.FirstName,
                                        value: item.FistName
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. I have tried before, but still no luck for me.
I think I have either messed things up or simply misunderstood the concept......
please note my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an action that does the lookup and returns the result as a JsonResult

e.g.

```
public ActionResult FirstNameLookup(string firstName)
{
    var contacts = FindContacts(firstname);

    return Json(contacts.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
Turns out the controller method is the source of this problem,
I have implemented something wrong in the method so the autocomplete crash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve all your problems but here are a couple of edits you can make.

1. you don't need the "?firstname=" part of the url since you are using the data parameter for you ajax request.
2. rather than grabbing your search term with $('#FirstName').val(), try using the term property of the request object (request.term).

for example:

```
$('#FirstName').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Contact/FirstNameLookup",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            "firstName": request.term 
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.FirstName,
                                    value: item.FistName
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.
But at last, I have found that the problem is related to the controller, and it is only a tiny bug which crash the autocomplete function.......